# How to create a base view controller with default overrides in a Swift project

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like **all controllers** (subclasses of `UIViewController, UITableViewController` etc.) in my project have the same overriding.

```
<SOME DEFINITION> { // some definition like this that could be used in all view controllers
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }
    override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool { return true }
}
```

I tried to create a subclass of `UIViewController` with the shared overriding, but it cannot be used to `UITableViewController` and `UITabViewController`.

Protocol couldn't make it because it cannot declare override without real inheritance.

Swift doesn't support macro which similar with `#define` in C/C++.

Comment: @LeoDabus So you are suggesting to override in an extension?

Comment: Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

Comment: @Aidy I think the only solution would be to subclass each of those controllers

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes that's the way I am using. I'd like to know whether there is any better way.

Comment: @Aidy I don't think so.

Comment: Are you saying you want to declare these properties once and to be able to call or change them from any view controller in your app?

Comment: @elliott-io Yes, I'd like to make it appear only once and all my view controller can share those basic settings.

Comment: @Aidy, you can do this using a singleton, though you will need to assign the value in each view controller.

Comment: @elliott-io I don't quite get it. Do you mean to make a singleton class with the shared settings. Then in every view controller, the singleton has to be invoked in each specific function? E.g. ```override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return MySingleton.shared.prefersStatusBarHidden }```

Comment: Yeah, you need to set it on each view controller. Alternatively, you can set it for the whole app. Is that what you want, to set it for the whole app in one spot in your source code?

Comment: @elliott-io It's partly. Except appears once, I also would like the modification only happen in one place when add/delete an override.